# My native country of Pakistan does not accept dual nationality, am I still a citizen?

Tags: citizenship, dual-citizenship, pakistani-citizen

My native country Pakistan has dual nationality arrangements with [16 countries](http://www.dgip.gov.pk/files/immigration.aspx#DualNationality). What happens if I acquire a citizenship of a country which is not in this list?

If I do not renounce my Pakistani citizenship, will I be still a citizen of Pakistan or will I automatically lose Pakistani citizenship?

Comment: Note that the list you link to says that "The nationals of these countries are not required to renounce their nationality while acquiring Pakistan Citizenship."  It does not say anything about Pakistani nationals who become nationals of the listed countries.  A strict reading of the linked page, therefore, leads to the conclusion that you must renounce your citizenship if you are naturalized in any other country, including the 16.  The question of what happens if you get naturalized elsewhere and do not renounce your Pakistani citizenship, as you no doubt noticed, is not discussed.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Pakistani nationality law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistani_nationality_law):

> s.14  Dual Citizenship or nationality not permitted.  If you hold a citizenship outside of Pakistan the Pakistani citizenship is terminated
>
> - Unless one decides to renounce the other
> - Unless one has citizenship in Britain or its colonies
> - Unless one is a female married to a man who is not a Pakistani citizen
>
> s.14A     Renunciation of citizenship.    If a person pledges allegiance or becomes a citizen of another country they have forfeited their Pakistani citizenship
>
> - The exception is if a child (under the age of 21) who does not have his Pakistani citizenship and would like to resume it after turning 21 is allowed to do so.

The above text is copied from Wikipedia but there are links to the actual text of the Pakistani Citizenship Act of 1951 which says the same thing.